# SwiftUI: Publish updates to custom shape

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, publish-subscribe

In the following SwiftUI code I have 3 main components:

`TestView` - Holds a `TestClass` instance, displays `MyShape`, and updates the count of the `TestClass` instance on tap.

`TestClass` - A simple class to store a `count`, which gets published when it's changed.

`MyShape` - A simple shape whose position (should) change as the count of the `TestClass` instance in `TestView` changes.

**The issue** is that the position of `MyShape` does not change when the count updates.

I know that the count is being updated because if I display the count in a Text view it changes on tap, so while the count is changing, the shape is not updating when the count changes. Why is the shape not updating / why is the publisher not reaching the shape?

```
struct TestView: View {

    @ObservedObject var counter: TestClass = TestClass()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            MyShape(counter: counter)
                .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 50)
                .onTapGesture {
                    counter.count += 1
                }
        }
    }
}



class TestClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var count = 0
}



struct MyShape: Shape {
    
    var counter: TestClass
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: counter.count, y: counter.count))
        return path
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI only updates a `View` or `Shape` when its properties change.

Right now, `MyShape` never changes its properties after the first render since `TestClass` is a reference type (ie `class` in this case) -- SwiftUI just sees that the properties are identical and doesn't bother to render a new version of `MyShape`, even though one of the internal properties on `TestClass` has changed.

Within a `View`, we can use the `@ObservedObject` property wrapper so that the `View` knows to update when an `ObservableObject`'s `@Published` properties change (like you do in `TestView`), but that wrapper isn't available in a `Shape`.

The easiest solution here is to pass `count` instead of `counter`. `count` is an `Int` (ie a value type), meaning whenever it changes, SwiftUI will know to update the `Shape`:

```
struct TestView: View {

    @ObservedObject var counter: TestClass = TestClass()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            MyShape(count: counter.count)
                .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 50)
                .onTapGesture {
                    counter.count += 1
                }
        }
    }
}

class TestClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var count = 10
}

struct MyShape: Shape {
    var count: Int
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: count, y: count))
        return path
    }
}
```

An alternate solution that may be fit the principals of SwiftUI a little better is to change your model into a `struct`. Then, the model can be passed to the `Shape` and since it's a value type, the `Shape` will update. This is, of course, assuming that your real-world model is more complex and has more than one property that the `Shape` will need -- otherwise, keeping the original solution of just exposing what it needs (ie the `Int`) is probably a better one.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var counter: TestStruct = TestStruct()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            MyShape(counter: counter)
                .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 50)
                .onTapGesture {
                    counter.count += 1
                }
        }
    }
}

struct TestStruct {
    var count = 10
}

struct MyShape: Shape {
    var counter: TestStruct
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: counter.count, y: counter.count))
        return path
    }
}
```

*Note: I updated the initial `count` so that it was easier to tap the view at the beginning*